# Flutter: How to crop text depending on available space?

Tags: text, dart, widget, overflow, flutter

How to crop text depending on available space?

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502304/how-to-automatically-scale-a-widget-to-fit-different-screen-sizes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but there's no working answer.

Currently, this code

```
            return new GridTile(
              child: new Card(
                elevation: 3.0,
                child: new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        document['title'],
                        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        document['text'],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            );
```

Gives this result:

[image]

I tried using *overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis*, but the text becomes 1 line long. Specifying the text line length is a bad idea, because on different screen sizes results will vary.

**How to make so that the text crops, fits or wraps itself into available space?**

Comment: Decided to use ListView with Card instead - it looks better too

Answer (score 10):

Setting `overflow` behavior should do

```
  new Text(
    widget.text,
    // softWrap: true,
    overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
  )
```

See also [Flutter: How to hide or show more text within certain length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572747/flutter-how-to-hide-or-show-more-text-within-certain-length/49572969#49572969)

Comment: tried overflow: TextOverflow.fade, but nothing has changed, the bottom is still overflowed by 88 pixels

Comment: Is the overflow actually from the `Text` widget, or is it from one of the parents?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15465#issuecomment-382458700 looks similar to what you seem to try to accomplish, perhaps it contains something helpful.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it works but you need to add `maxLines: 1` too to your `Text`. But the problem is it fades the text vertically, I was looking for horizontal. Can you help? EDIT: Setting `softWrap: false` seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the text widget Inside Expanded or Flexible widget and use overflow.ellipsis this worked for me

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
         Flexible(
             child: Text(
             "Some Very long Text or random generated strings ",
             overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
             softWrap: true,
             ),
        ),
    ],
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
extension StringX on String {
  String get overflow => Characters(this)
  .replaceAll(Characters(''), Characters('\u{200B}'))
  .toString();
}


Text(
 textString.overflow,
 overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
 maxLines: 1,
)
```

It works for me.

source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18761#issuecomment-812390920